# Fluent assertion - compare empty objects

Tags: c#, code-generation, fluent-assertions

I'm generating a C# solution using another project.
The generated solution contains multiple classes and a unit test file for each class.

A unit test creates two instances of a class and compares them.
For the comparison, I chose FluentAssertion (I tried other external comparators like ComareNetObjects, but it took too long on objects with large depth).

The instances are compared as following:

```
inst1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(inst2);
```

**The problem is that some of the generated classes have no fields or properties**.
For those classes, the unit test creates two instances (with no members) and compares them. The equivalency check throws:

> *System.InvalidOperationException(0x80131509): No members were found for comparison. Please specify some members to include in the comparison or choose a more meaningful assertion.*

I don't want to expand the generated classes only for the tests, nor check for each instance's properties.

Is there a way to customize this behavior in FluentAssertion?

Comment: What do you mean with "the objects are empty"? Are they null? In that case, you can use `inst1.Should().NotBeNull()` before your check.

Comment: Did you go through https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/ ?

Comment: `A unit test creates two instances` how created instance could be null?

Comment: Are those objects the same type? Do they have matching Porperty names? Are all properties private? I think we need some more context.

Comment: I meant empty objects as objects with no properties or fields, as the exception state 'no members were found'. I edited the question.

Comment: Quick & Dirty fix: Maye `inst1.GetType().GetProperties().Should().NotBeEmpty()` before the check works for you?

Comment: @SomeBody, most of the objects does have members, so I rather not

Comment: Can you describe how you want to compare types without any properties?

Comment: @JonasNyrup, I think type comparison is the first thing you check in equivalency, properties after. I think I would like the same here. A comparison that doesn't break on instances with no members..